# function in R to determine sample sizes to compare population means

Tags: r

Looking to determine sample sizes for both my experimental and control groups (I want only a small portion of my participants in my experimental condition, not a 50/50 split) in order to compare population means.

I'm using the bpower function from the Hmisc R package, specifically bsamsize to compare population proportions, but was wondering if there was an equivalent function for comparing means.

Answer (score 1):

The `pwr` package has functions for computing power/sample size with unequal groups for both means and proporions.  Look at the `pwr.t2n.test` function.